# Duplicates in results from .ToArray in LinQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I did a query which should return only 3 rows, but I get 36 rows with the rest being duplicates.

```
var query = from a in db.as
            join b in db.bs on a.pri equals b.for
            join c in db.cs on b.pri equals c.for
            where b.Age == age
            select new string[]
        {
            a.Name,
            a.Gender,
            b.Amount,
            c.Location,
        };
string[][] results = query.ToArray();
return results;
```

Could it be the .ToArray causing it to have multiple duplicates?

Comment: share the complete query

Comment: Can you post the whole query?

Comment: No, `ToArray` is surely not the cause. More likely you have a problem in your query.

Comment: i ran the query that returns only 3 rows.

Comment: why do you take string[] in linq query... I think you should remove it.

Comment: i'm returning an jagged array from this method

Comment: Do you have in those 'bs' multiple records for a particular 'a.pri' (or in the 'cs' multiple records for 'b.pri')? That's the reason you get duplicate results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick solution is make use of Distinct method

```
string[][] results = query.Distinct().ToArray();
```

which may resolve your problem.

if not please share the data of you table....

Comment: With a Distinct you are just hiding the fact that the query return too many results.

Comment: @Hans Kesting - I agress with you as per me there is no more info avaiable form the question op ask so I put this solution but I must say there is problem with his joins